# how to Keep user files after deploy? tomcat / java / aws

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, filesystems, tomcat8

Hi I have been getting troubles with the deploys in an application java/tomcat in EBS, every time I made a deploy al the user files are deleted because all the folders related to it are been placed in the webapp folder, because of that I need to move those users folders out of webapp, or at least it is the solution that several websites said. Based on it they said I need to add something like this

```
<Context docBase="/home/ec2-user/files/" path="/userFiles" />
```

on the server.xml file, but it is not working in my case, I guess it is because AWS elastic bean stalk . Someone have an advice or a solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not write the user data to a database?

Comment: Im talking about files like videos, img, pdf.

Comment: You should really look into storing those files on S3 instead of on the web server.